# tflite package has a deprecated api in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using tflite in my flutter project but this package has deprecated Api, so my question if I upload my app to the play store and apple store does it make problems with that ? and how can we fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

If an API is deprecated it can still be used without any problem. But the reason it should not be used is that if an API is deprecated, it means that it is still supported but support might end in the near future, because alternative better APIs exist. If you want to avoid deprecated APIs completely you will have to find a different package with the same functionality that does not use deprecated APIs. But for now going with tflite package does not do any harm, but there may come a time in the future, when the deprecated APIs it uses, will not be supported anymore. Then your application will stop working.